# Is it possible to run a .sh file on my local fritzbox router?

Tags: sh, cloudflare, dynamic-ip, fritzbox

Hey is it possible to run a .sh file on my local fritzbox router?

```bash
NEW_IP=`curl -s http://ipv4.icanhazip.com`
CURRENT_IP=`cat /path/to/current/ip.txt`

if [ "$NEW_IP" = "$CURRENT_IP" ]
then
        echo "No Change in IP Address"
else
#domain-one
curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/{zone_id_for_domain_one}/dns_records/{dns_record_id_for_domain_one_record_one}" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: {my_email}" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: {global_api_key}" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"type":"A","name":"domain-one.com","content":"'$NEW_IP'","ttl":1,"proxied":true}'
echo $NEW_IP > /path/to/current/ip.txt
fi
```

I want to update my cloudflare IP address using this script. Is there some software or a hidden way I can run this file when the my IP changes or in a schedule?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you ssh into it?

Comment: Don't know how...